# I want to create a zoom in/ out effect in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

```js
var calendar = null;
    var datetime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
    let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    var slotLabel = '';
    var plusMinus = 0;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            timeZone: 'UTC',
            slotMinTime: '06:00',
            slotMaxTime: '19:00',
            slotDuration: slotLabel,
            slotLabelInterval: slotLabel,
            weekNumbers: true,
            weekText: "Week",
            initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
            height: 650,
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
            },
            allDay: false,
            editable: true,
            resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Manager',
            initialDate: today,
            businessHours: [
                {
                    daysOfWeek: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    startTime: '07:00',
                    endTime: '18:00'
                }

            ],
            resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
            resources: [{
                id: 'a',
                title: 'Employee 1'
            },
            {
                id: 'b',
                title: 'Employee 2'
            },
            {
                id: 'c',
                title: 'Employee 3'
            },
            {
                id: 'd',
                title: 'Employee 4'
            }
            ],
            events: [{
                title: 'Event 1',
                start: today + 'T07:30:00',
                end: today + 'T12:00:00',
                resourceId: 'a'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event 2',
                start: today + 'T09:30:00',
                end: today + 'T14:00:00',
                resourceId: 'b'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event 3',
                start: today + 'T08:30:00',
                end: today + 'T12:00:00',
                resourceId: 'c'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event 4',
                start: today + 'T10:30:00',
                end: today + 'T14:00:00',
                resourceId: 'd'
            }
            ]
        });
        calendar.render();
    });

    var value = 0;
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("displayValue");
    var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
    var hourOutput = $("#hours")[0];
    var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
    hourOutput.innerHTML = hours;

    $('.slider').change(function () {
        var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
        hourOutput.innerHTML = hours;
        slotLabel = hours + ':' + '00';
        if (calendar) {
            calendar.setOption('slotLabelInterval', slotLabel);
            calendar.setOption('slotDuration', slotLabel);
        }
    });
    
    Mousetrap.bind('ctrl++', function (e) {
        if (plusMinus < 8) {
            plusMinus = plusMinus + 2;
            Plus = plusMinus + ':' + '00';
            if (calendar) {
                calendar.setOption('slotLabelInterval', Plus);
                calendar.setOption('slotDuration', Plus);
            }
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+-', function (e) {
        if (plusMinus > 0 && plusMinus <= 8) {
            plusMinus = plusMinus - 2;
            Minus = plusMinus + ':' + '00';
            if (calendar) {
                calendar.setOption('slotLabelInterval', Minus);
                calendar.setOption('slotDuration', Minus);
            }
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
a {
            color: var(--bs-link-color);
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #storlekslider {
            width: 30%;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.9/index.global.min.js'></script>
    <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mousetrap/1.6.3/mousetrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <h3 id="displayValue">
            <span id="hours" style="display:none;">min</span> 
        </h3>
        <label style="font-size:medium">Duartion</label>
        <input type="range" min="60" max="480" step="0.5" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange" style="height:9px;">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

By user hoovering the calendar and press CTRL + MouseWheelUp/ MouseWheelDown to change the following values:
slotduration = X,
slotLabelInterval = X

As they zoom out we change it to:
slotduration = X,
slotLabelInterval = X

This should give the effect of zooming in and out of calendar.

But I have trouble overriding the standard function to zoom in/ out in browser.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the zoom of the div containing the calendar?

Comment: Hello @AriadniMak i haven't tried.

Comment: I tried changing the zoom of the div but it's not effecting calendar

Comment: Created a zoom in/ out by applying shortcut key (ctrl + / ctrl - ) in Fullcalendar with library file of mousetrap. Run code snippet and have look.